# Pentaho Carte Rest Services giving 302

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to evaluate Carte and add a job I created in the Spoon designer to a local file repository I also created.

I created the  xml to add the job and wrote a test program.

The response however is always 302 - any idea how I can get past that to actually call the service ?

I have read that 302 means redirect so go grab the 'Location' header and make another call. In this case the location header again is "http://localhost:8181/kettle/addJob", and re-calling results in a further http 302 response. I seem to be stuck in a loop now ..

```
        String fileName = "C:\\format.xml";
        String url = "http://localhost:8181/kettle/addJob";
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        List authPrefs = new ArrayList();
        authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
                AuthPolicy.AUTH_SCHEME_PRIORITY, authPrefs);

        Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("cluster",
                "cluster");
        AuthScope scope = new AuthScope("localhost", AuthScope.ANY_PORT);
        httpClient.getState().setCredentials(scope, creds);
        AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme("Basic", BasicScheme.class);
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
        String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(fileName));
        post.setRequestBody(xml);

        int result = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

Comment: This is probably made for humans using web-browsers. Probably you are getting some more headers, like cookies or similar. Can you try to enable cookies, or at least paste the cookies here?

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Here are all the 3 headers returned Location=http://localhost:8181/kettle/addJob/, Content-Length=0, Server=Jetty(6.1.21). There are no cookies returned at all unfortunately.

Comment: Are you able to get the expected content using `curl` or similar?

Comment: @orion_kid can you please shed some light on integrating carte with pentaho tool, and what role does a repository play. I tried executing a job by hitting carte rest api but keep getting this error saying unable to connect to repository. My main concern here is that how the carte server would come to know that which job to execute, where would it get that informaiton from. I also tried adding my local carte server as a slave server in transformation tab in the tool. But I do not have any idea about this repository stuff.